# How to unit test spring bean definitions?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, code-coverage, spring-bean

I have defined several spring beans via `@Bean`.

```
@Bean
void SomeClass someClass() {
return new SomeClass();
}
```

But these are not covered by unit tests as I use `@Mock` to mock the classes, and beans are not instantiated in unit tests.

Now test coverage is failing because spring bean definition lines are not covered, is there any way to fix it ?

We use Jacoco coverage.

Note: I am not using @Configuration, rather passing the class to Application context

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` files are normally excluded from code-coverage tests by rule. Running the application with `@SpringBootTest` (if you're using Boot) may also cause these to be marked as executed.

Comment: I am not using @Configuration on top of bean definition class, rather passing the bean definition class to Application context.

Comment: @AjaySabarish ..._why_? I have been working with Spring for 13 years, and I've never seen that.

Comment: That's how our code repo is written, a top level bean is defined and the source class is passed as nested bean definition. Is there any way I can test/exclude the source class ?